# I can't reach the doGet method with a simple form

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, get

Sorry for this dummy question, but something is going wrong with this little sample :

```
<div id="footer">
    <form action="debut" method="GET">
        <button id="btn-start" class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Commencer</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

I'm trying to call a servlet declared like this :

```
@WebServlet("/debut")
public class DebutServlet {
```

Why the action does not work ?

Thank you

Comment: you can check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call the name of the servlet :

```
<form action="DebutServlet " method="GET">
    <button id="btn-start" class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Commencer</button>
</form>
```

Also better to make annotation in same name of Servlet :

```
@WebServlet("/DebutServlet")
public class DebutServlet {
```